# How to display form action status message after successful deletion?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

A form deletes all the records stored in MySql database associated with filtered id on a page like `example.php?id=7` and redirected to the same page up on successful deletion of the records.

The code details are as following:

```
if ((isset($_POST['id'])) && ($_POST['id'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));


  mysql_select_db($database_example, $example);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $example) or die(mysql_error());


  $deleteGoTo = "example.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}

$colname_deleterecord = "5";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $colname_deleterecord = $_GET['id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_example, $example);
$query_deleterecord = sprintf("SELECT id, user_name, email, address FROM users WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_deletetrecord, "int"));
$deleterecord = mysql_query($query_deleterecord, $example) or die(mysql_error());
$row_deleterecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($deleteecord);
$totalRows_deleterecord = mysql_num_rows($deleterecord);
```

---

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label>
      <input type="submit" name="Delete Record" id="Delete Record" value="Delete Record" />
    </label>
    <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_deleterecord['id']; ?>" />
  </form>
```

How to display the form action status message like ("Record deleted") on the same page with pure php syntax after the records are deleted successfully?

Comment: whatdo you mean with "on the same page"?It seems to me that you are redirecting after the deletion

Comment: The page is being redirected to the same page after successful form action `header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));`
`action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store action message into session .. and you and didplay like this if you are using any MVC architecture  :-

```
 $this->Session->setFlash('Record Deleted.');
```

Try this..

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem finally.

The trick is to assign a query string (key/value pair) to the header location variable or directly replace the header location variable with it's associated value.

Then to switch the query string (key/value pair) in association with function and form variable and wrap a div with it where the form action status message should be displayed on the page after successful deletion.